# Node application doesn't start with "zeromq.node: undefined symbol: sodium_init" message

Tags: node.js, zeromq, ubuntu-20.04, zeromq-js

**Problem**

Node application not starts with the following message:

```
node: symbol lookup error: /home/user/nodeapp/node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zeromq.node: undefined symbol: sodium_init
```

Application uses ZeroMQ.js having the following in `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "zeromq": "^6.0.0-beta.16"
  }
```

Starting application failed with above message. I'm running:

- ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- node v16.18.1
- npm 8.19.2
- libzmq3-dev (4.3.2-2ubuntu1)

**Workaround**

Application starts and run normally if I remove `zeromq` module and install it with the following command:

```
npm install zeromq@6.0.0-beta.16 --zmq-shared
```

But the next time when I run `npm install` the problem returns.

**Question**

Is it possible to not manually install ZeroMQ.js Version 6.0.0 in my environment to avoid application failure with `undefined symbol` message?

Unfortunately I can't upgrade Ubuntu and Node now due to system requirements.

Comment: `libsodium` (for encryption) [seems to be a runtime dependency](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/issues/529#issuecomment-1320503947), have you tried installing it?

Comment: Unfortunately, `unable to locate package ...` while trying to install `lipsodium` or `lipsodium-dev`

Comment: You misspelled `libsodium` there, it's with a `b` in stead of a `p`. But I can confirm that it won't solve the issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a PR for solving this bug:
https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/pull/553

Hopefully should be merged and released soon. So upstep your `zeromq` npm-package after that.

Comment: Thank you very much for good news! Will mark your answer as accepted after upcoming release.

Comment: Thank you. Even pushed a quick-fix. As the PR mentioned does not cover all use-cases...

https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/pull/554

I will keep you posted as well here.

Comment: At least v6.0.0-beta.17 released and it's ok for me now. I saw your discussion with developer and I beleive you definitely helped to solve this issue in any way. So I mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Is this really fixed in v6.0.0-beta.17? we are still having the same issue on `arm`

Comment: @kaptan Just tested install in `x64` and `arm64` target architectures with success. But need to say that OS was upgraded to 22.04 but `node` left the same.

Comment: @Serg thanks for the update. we are having issues on Raspbian `Debian 11 (bullseye)`. I can see that ubuntu 22 is based on `bookworm`. I wonder if that might be the reason that it works for you.